# Using Socket.io, Angular, JWT Authenitication data not available till after user authenticated refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, socket.io, jwt

I am using Angular and Socket.io, socket-jwt for authentication the sockets, and angular-socket-io on the front end.

When the page loads, the client attempts to connect to the socket.io server.  It is denied because their is no token established for the client.

When a socket connection is established I am decoding the token on the server and then I want to emit data to the client including the socket.id where I will update the model and view.

After a user authenticates, it is not until the page is refreshed that the socket.io data is available and then emits to the client.

How do I go about establishing the socket.io connection after the user has logged in and making the data available?

I have tried calling my socket factory, using socket.connect() and io.connect() inside the login controller after a user logs in.

socket factory

```
 app.factory('socket', function ($window, socketFactory) {
    var token = $window.localStorage.yourTokenKey;
    var myIoSocket = 'http://localhost:8080';
    var socket = io.connect(myIoSocket, {'query' : 'token=' + token});
    return socket;
});
```

login function in login controller

```
$scope.login = function() {
    AuthService.login($scope.user)
        .then(function(msg) {

             socket.connect();
             $state.go('home');
        }, function() {
           console.log('Login Failed');
    });
};
```

server code

```
var socketIo = require('socket.io');

var io = socketIo.listen(server);

io.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: config.secret,
    handshake: true
}));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    var token = socket.handshake.query.token;
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

    var user = {
        name: decoded._doc.name,
        userId: decoded._doc._id,
        socketId: socket.id
    };

    socket.emit(‘other event’, user);
});
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to make an AJAX call to grab that initial token if `$window.localStorage.yourTokenKey` is empty.

Comment: Either AJAX, or you need to allow the socket connection to exist, but tag it unauthorized, to be able to emit values from the server to it.